# The element type 'Stream<dynamic>' can't be assigned to the list type 'Stream<Query Snapshot<Object?>>'

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

---

```
    Stream<List<QuerySnapshot>> getData() {
Stream stream1 = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Gib Role').where('id', isEqualTo: 'false').orderBy('timestamp').snapshots();
Stream stream2 = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Register').where('id', isEqualTo: 'true').orderBy('timestamp').snapshots();
return StreamZip([stream1,stream2]); }
```

the above error was visible on stream 1 and stream 2 ,how to clear this error, anyone can please help me

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Stream<List<QuerySnapshot<Object?>>> getData() {
Stream<QuerySnapshot<Object?>> stream1 = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Gib Role').where('id', isEqualTo: 'false').orderBy('timestamp').snapshots();
Stream<QuerySnapshot<Object?>> stream2 = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Register').where('id', isEqualTo: 'true').orderBy('timestamp').snapshots();
return StreamZip([stream1,stream2]); }
```